# substring in AsyncTask cause app to force quit

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code:

```
package com.jamie.translate;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Created by Jamie on 25/6/2015.
 */
public class TranslateTextTask extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, String> {
    TextView t;
    String result = "";
    String sourceText = "";
    String sourceLanguage = "";
    String resultLanguage = "";

    public TranslateTextTask(String _sourceText, String _sourceLanguage, String _resultLanguage) {
        this.sourceText = _sourceText;
        this.sourceLanguage = _sourceLanguage;
        this.resultLanguage = _resultLanguage;
    }

    protected void d(String tag, String errorMessage) {
        MainActivity.showNormalMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, errorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(TextView... params) {
        this.t = params[0];
        return GetTranslatedText();
    }

    final String GetTranslatedText() {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        String langPair;
        URI uri = null;
        final HttpClient httpClient;
        final HttpGet request;
        final HttpResponse[] response = new HttpResponse[1];
        final BufferedReader reader = null;
        final String JSONResult = "";
        String translatedString;

        if(sourceText.length() > 500) {
            MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, "Source text can only be max. 500 characters");
            return "";
        }

        d("Test", "Tag2");try {
            String x = ("en - English").substring(0, 2);
            String y = resultLanguage.substring(0, 2);

            langPair =
                    sourceLanguage.substring(0, 2)
                            + "|"
                            + resultLanguage.substring(0, 2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, "Source language or result language invalid.");
            return "";
        }

        d("Test", "Tag3");try {
            uri = new URI(builder.scheme("http")
                    .authority("api.mymemory.translated.net")
                    .appendPath("get")
                    .appendQueryParameter("langpair", langPair)
                    .appendQueryParameter("q", sourceText)
                    .build()
                    .toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, "Failed to build HTTP request URL.");
            return "";
        }

        d("Test", "Tag4");try {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, "Failed to build HTTP request.");
            return "";
        }

        d("Test", "Tag5");try {
            // response = httpClient.execute(request);
            d("Test", "Tag6");try {
                response[0] = (httpClient.execute(request));
                return MainActivity.handleTranslateRequest(MainActivity.applicationContext, response[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, e.toString());
                return "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, e.toString());
            // MainActivity.showErrorMessage(MainActivity.applicationContext, "Failed to complete HTTP request.");
            return "";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        t.setText(result);
    }
}
```

And I start this code by:

```
new TranslateTextTask(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.source)).getText(), translateSourceLanguage, translateResultLanguage).execute((EditText) findViewById(R.id.result));
```

Example values of values of variable in debug process include

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.source)).getText(): "Hi"
translateSourceLanguage: "en - English"
translateResultLanguage: "it - Italiano"
```

There was no internet connection problem.
During debug process, I set enough breakpoints and found the force quit problem happened on this line:

```
String x = ("en - English").substring(0, 2);
```

What can I do to solve this problem? This seems to be a super-simple problem but can't stop it at all.

## Edit

LogCat message:

```
06-25 18:41:04.318    9337-9534/com.jamie.translate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.jamie.translate, PID: 9337
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:376)
            at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:108)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:267)
            at com.jamie.translate.MainActivity.showNormalMessage(MainActivity.java:26)
            at com.jamie.translate.TranslateTextTask.d(TranslateTextTask.java:35)
            at com.jamie.translate.TranslateTextTask.GetTranslatedText(TranslateTextTask.java:60)
            at com.jamie.translate.TranslateTextTask.doInBackground(TranslateTextTask.java:41)
            at com.jamie.translate.TranslateTextTask.doInBackground(TranslateTextTask.java:21)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Force quit = Stack trace. Stack trace = what the error is. With no stack trace we can't help you :(

Comment: @Selvin, I guess not. I'll read it though, but `("en - English").substring(0, 2)` doesn't look that it will generate any problem.

Comment: I'll try generating a stack trace......

Comment: `MainActivity.showErrorMessage` looks terrible ... `MainActivity.applicationContext` too

Comment: I can;t see anything that's going to help me in logcat... maybe it was too verbose

Comment: Can anyone solve this problem...... finally found the logcat message.

Comment: You can't show toast from backgroud thread .... which is easy to google if you google for second part of the exception ...

Comment: what is MainActivity.showErrorMessage??

Comment: remove showerror in method  GetTranslatedText()

Comment: Would anyone mind... to change the duplicate question to another one? It was just not this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not touch UI (i.e. posting Toasts or update TextView etc) on your `doInBackground()`. If you need to update UI you need to either do this in `onPostExecute()` or use `onProgressUpdate()` if that would fit.